# How-To Integrate FreePBX Phonebook and Users with LDAP?

Tags: ldap, freepbx

I'm using FreePBX and want to use phonebook integrated with ldap. I googled and nothing very specific come up. Do you guys have any experience about the subject?

Answer (score 1):

I use trixbox, and don't use LDAP as of yet it, but the package is called php-ldap. "yum install php-ldap" 
It may be not quite the same directory for config /var/www/html/web-meetme/lib/adLDAP.php

Interested to know the comparison, apologies if it's not a direct answer!

Comment: additionally, the GosaProject is a management utility for LDAP 
https://oss.gonicus.de/labs/gosa/
may provide some extra info for you

Comment: also is this for the phone directory on the phones itself, or within FreePBX?